# Flex/AS3: Data binding through a refenced property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding

I have:

class A: with a property "data:ArrayCollection". It's my data source (data provider) and has bitmaps.

class B: has an instance of A (called "Ainst") and calls the following method: C.init( Ainst.data). To pass the data provider to Object C.

class C: has a reference of the data provider "data" (because of "init" method). It shows the arrayCollection into Images as: Image.source = data.getItemAt(0).

But C never updates its images, that is, data binding doesn't work with this scheme. I've put [Bindable] meta-tag in all properties and even classes.

class A:

```
public class A{ [Bindable]public var data:ArrayCollection; }
```

class B:

```
public class B{ [Bindable]public var Ainst:A; public var Cinst:C; public function init(){ Cinst = new C(); Cinst.init(A.data) } }
```

class C: An image menu with 3 items (bitmaps)

```
            <s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*"
                  horizontalAlign="center"
                  paddingTop="10"
                  paddingBottom="10"
                  gap="10">


            <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[ 
    [Bindable] public var _images:ArrayCollection; 
    public function init( images:ArrayCollection ):void{

                    _images = images;
}   
        ]]>
            </fx:Script>
            <ms:Image id="PreviousButton" smoothBitmapContent="true" width="55" height="55" source="@Embed(source='/../figures/upArrow.png')"/>
                <ms:Image id="TopItem" smoothBitmapContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" x="12.5" source="{_images.getItemAt(0)}" />
                <ms:Image id="MiddleItem" smoothBitmapContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" x="12.5" source="{_images.getItemAt(1)}"/>
                <ms:Image id="BottomItem" smoothBitmapContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" x="12.5" source="{_images.getItemAt(3)}"/><!-- getItemAt(2).image -->
                <ms:Image id="NextButton" smoothBitmapContent="true" width="55" height="55" source="@Embed(source='/../figures/downArrow.png')"/>
            </s:VGroup>
```

Any thought? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code to understand details.

Comment: What programming language did you used before ActionScript?

Comment: c++,c,java,c#, etc, etc. The problem is I wrote everything on the fly in the same forum's box. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the function getItemAt (_images.getItemAt(0)) is NOT Bindable.

Comment: no, no. Look at this: "However, the data binding expression myAC.getItemAt(0) is triggered when an array element changes. Therefore, the text2 Text control is updated when you click button1, while text1 is not. When using an array element as the source of a data binding expression, you should use the ArrayCollection.getItemAt() method in the binding expression. " From: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_4.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your class `A`:

```
public class A{
    [Bindable]
    public var data:ArrayCollection;
}
```

The property `data` here isn't static. So it is related to instance of `A` but not `A` itself. Now take a look at constructor of `B`:

```
public function init(){ 
    Cinst = new C(); 
    Cinst.init(A.data);
}
```

And its field declaration:

```
[Bindable]
public var Ainst:A;
```

As you can see in a line

```
Cinst.init(A.data);
```

you're referring `data` as a static property. You should use:

```
public function init(){ 
    Cinst = new C(); 
    Cinst.init(Ainst.data);
}
```

instead.

And please keep ActionScript [naming and coding conventions](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions). Place statements in a separate lines and start identifiers with lowercase letter. It allows to read your code easier.

Comment: Thanks for your time but this code was given as a pseudo one. So that's not the problem. I think the issue is that I coudn't get the bind event when the array changes.

Comment: @Manel, stop using pseudo code and show the real one?  Whatever you're doing, it seems overly complicated.

Comment: ok, sorry, but original classes are really large... I've found the solution and I'll give you all an explanation later. It was related to clone Bitmap's when you are updating an ArrayCollection